# Problem with Passport NodeJs authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, passport-local

I am using **Passport Local** for authentication. But whenever I try to login it is just using **failureRedirect** and not creating Cookie. I have checked my code so many times but it still does the same. What I have observed that my passport.js file is not executing for some resion.

**My App Index File**

```js
//Main app index file
const express=require('express');
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
const app=express();
const port=8000;
const layout=require('express-ejs-layouts');
const db=require('./config/mongoose');
const session=require('express-session');
const passport=require('passport');
const localStrategy=require('./config/passport-local-strategy');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static('./assets'));

app.use(layout);

app.set('layout extractStyles',true);
app.set('layout extractScripts',true);

app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views','./views');

app.use(session({
    name:'Codeial',
    secret:'Something',
    saveUninitialized:false,
    resave:false,
    cookie:{
        maxAge:(1000*60*100)
    }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/',require('./routes'));

app.listen(port,function(err){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(`Error:${err}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`Sever runs on port:${port}`);
});
```

**My index router file**

```js
//index router file
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();

const control=require('../controller/router_controller');
const control2=require('../controller/user');

router.get('/',control.route);
router.use('/user',require('./users.js'));

console.log('Router is working');

module.exports=router;
```

**User Router File**

```js
//user router file
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const passport=require('passport');
const pro=require('../controller/profile')
const user=require('../controller/user');

router.get('/profile',pro.profile);
router.get('/sign-in',user.sign_in);
router.get('/sign-up',user.sign_up);
router.post('/create',user.create);

router.post('/create-session',passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect:'/user/sign-in'}),user.createSession);

module.exports=router;
```

**Passport and Passport local strategy file**

```js
//passport and passport local strategy
const passport=require('passport');
const LocalPassport=require('passport-local').Strategy;

const User=require('../model/user');

passport.use(new LocalPassport({usernameField:'email'},function(email,password,done){
    User.findOne({email:email},function(err,user){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log('Error while finding data for authentication');
            return done(err);
        }
        if(!user||user.password!=password)
        {
            return done(null,false);
        }
        return done(null,user);
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
   done(null,user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
    User.findById(id,function(err,user){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log('Error while finding data for authentication');
            return done(err);
        }
        done(null,user);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just find one bug in `serializeUser`, put `user.id` in callback not `done` try and don't use `return` in `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` like this:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
```

and remove this line in Passport file, because don't need to exports

```
module.exports=passport;
```

and use bodyParser module to parse body of requests to json

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: Still not working. What I can see is that my "passport js" file is working fine but the middleware "LocalPassport" is not accessing I don't know why. I have tested that already. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: w0o0o0o0o0w, dont use `module.exports=passport` in possport.js, I've updated my answer, please check it

Comment: Still no result, its the same case that passport.js file is accessing but not the middleware..... By the way thanks for your cooperation

Comment: still no success

Comment: Check the header of request, set content-type: application/json ... and show me the requset